# $\ln(\exp(x) + \exp(y) + \exp(z)) = x + y + z$ , iterates of $x - \ln(\exp(x)-1)$ and generalizations

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems, functional-equations

Let $x,y > 0$
Consider the equation

$$\ln(\exp(x) + \exp(y)) = x + y$$

Now it is clear (by symmetry) that if we express $y$ as function of $x$ or $x$ as a function of $y$ that is the same function.

So

$$f(x) = y , f(y) = x $$

This implies

$$f(f(x)) = x , f(f(y)) = y$$

So the analytic function $f(x)$ is an involution for $x>0$, yet not a rational function.

In fact we can explictly find $f(x)$.

$$f(x) = x - \ln(\exp(x) - 1)$$

You can see for yourself that $f(f(x)) = x$.

I wondered about continu iterations of this function.

I realized

$$f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(x)-1}\right)$$

Let

$$f(x) = \ln(L(\exp(x)))$$

Then it becomes clear that basicly we are iterating

$$L(x) =  \frac{x}{x-1}$$

for $x \neq 0, x \neq 1$.

This is well studied.

But then I started to wonder about complex numbers.

$$\ln(\exp(x) + \exp(y) + \exp(z)) = x + y + z$$

$$\ln(\exp(x) + \exp(y) + \exp(z) + \exp(a) ) = x + y + z + a$$

etc

How do those additions relate to the function $f(x)$ from above ?

Clearly

$$y = f(x) , z = f(x + f(x))$$

works for

$$\ln(\exp(x) + \exp(y) + \exp(z)) = x + y + z$$

however it did use

$$\ln(\exp(x) + \exp(y)) = x + y$$

as a restriction.

This looses a degree of freedom or something.

Notice iterations of $x + f(x)$  correspond to iterations of

$$L_2(x) = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$$

which is more complicated perhaps.

So finally I come to the main question :

$$\ln\left(\sum_n \exp(x_n)\right) = \sum_n x_n$$

What do we know about that equation ?

And in particular :

Let $x_n$ be linear independant and consider

$$A = \ln\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \exp(x_n)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$$

Does that even make sense ?
Does $A$ even converge ?

What can $A$ converge to ?
Does this relate to the fixpoints of $\exp(z)$ ?

what do we know about the $x_n$ ?